# How to build a Pub Sub application with RabbitMQ, Spring Boot and React

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, rabbitmq

I'm trying to build an application with a couple of services. One service publishes details to a rabbitMQ queue, another spring boot application has to consume them and send the correct details to the correct user. The front end is developed in reactJS. How can I implement the spring boot consuming and sending to the subscribed user part? Any reference is appreciated. Can I use the web socket in spring boot to this?

Comment: Did you manage to get any resources for your implementation? I have to develop using similar stack